# WCF REST API returned type .net application

Tags: .net, wcf, api, rest, int

I have an API that can returns multiple things that I don't know in advance so I have to put as return type `System.Object`.

I have some problems for some types. Like when it returns different objects its fine but when it returns an `System.Int32`, it doesn't work and tells me:

```
Cannot serialize parameter of type 'System.Int32' because it is not the exact type 'System.Object' in the method signature and is not in the known types collection.
```

Any idea ?

I know we can use ServiceKnownType but I'd like to know if there is other way to do it? I would need all the existing types (int, bool, string, etc..) in this ...

Comment: Do you have problem with Value types but not Reference types?  String is reference type so that is the strange part.

Comment: Yes value types, int, double, long etc ... when my service returns an object having types int, double, long, etc, it does this mistake. Else, its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Do not return System.Object type on service contracts, even when it WCF 4 REST. How default serializers/formatters could produce response for your contract.

You can return byte array, convert your System.Object into string and return it. Anyway you can always serialize your objects to XML or JSON and return as string.

Also link to forum with same question, maybe it helps you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-NL/wcf/thread/1f43e9b4-39a4-481b-88f0-18c7d4416745

Comment: I don't know why it works with objects(local one that we created) but not with integers, double, strings. It's because I don't know in advence what the API will return ... it can return an object, a string, an int, etc ... so thats why I put System.Object as return type. I can't really cast in string in case it's an object returned ? And I want the same API doing all that ... so I need a type that can take everything as System.Object but it just doesn't work with int32 and others.

Comment: Do not use System.Object, because WCF subsystem doesn't know how to serialize it. Maybe WCF 4 REST can, but anyway it's bad practice. You can create your own object, e.g with name "Details" and encapsulate there all what you need. Then all your contracts could use it, and you will be able to manually serialize it or say WCF how to do it.

Comment: And this could work in my case ? Like in some case, the service will return to the API : int or string(or whatever type it is) and other cases objects.

Comment: Not fully understand what you mean, but such approach works and worked before. Why should it not work by you?!

Comment: Because my Service can return every single types ... I don't know it in advance... it depends what we pass in parameter, it will execute something and maybe return an int, maybe a string, maybe an object(not System.Object), so that's why I put System.Object as my API returned type because I don't knowin advance what it will return ... and I have maybe 100 diffrents objects in my solution .... it might also returns List.

Comment: Than make your own contract serializer/formatter. I do not know nuances, but sounds like your API isn't pretty good. Try to review it and may be it helps you to avoid many problems. Maybe explain your contact and why there are so much objects than I can try help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a simple if statement that checks to see if it is a int and then you can convert it to a object. By the way integers are not able to become objects til they are a string so if I did this I would do a simple:

```
blah.toString();
```

and bam you can now use it as a object.

Comment: In case I'm returing another object ?

Comment: I don't know in advence what it will return ... I just need a type that can take everything.